# Unable to build/publish Azure Data Factory application

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-data-factory, cortana-intelligence

Every Data Factory application I try to create in visual studio 2015, even the sample ones, are unable to build or publish due to:

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error on every .json file.

Is there some important configuration I'm missing or some dependencies I need to add to the project? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We have an open bug on this and will fix in our next release.  The error is thrown during build, but you still should be able to go ahead and publish.  We'll look into this further to see why you are also blocked from publishing.  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: See my answer on this question. In my case it seems like VS recognizes different version of Azure SDK than WebPI.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in the extension. I have the same error in Visual Studio 2015 but if you open this project from VS 2013 (you need to download [separate extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/754d998c-8f92-4aa7-835b-e89c8c954aa5)) it should build and publish correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Your Azure SDK for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue. Visual Studio 2015 is offering Microsoft Azure SDK 2.8.2 as an update and telling the currently installed version is 2.8.1 and while I try to update it, Web Platform Installer tells 2.8.2 is installed and refuses to install it again.

[image: Azure SDK 2.8.1 in VS while 2.8.2 in WebPI]

Also, when I try to rebuild the DataFactory project, I get the following alert.

[image]

Going through the logs, I find the following message:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.CompositionFailedException: An exception was thrown while initializing part "Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSON.Package.Schema.CatalogJSONSchemaSelector".
---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Html.Package.Host.IdleTimeSource..ctor() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Html.Package.Host.VsWebEditorHost..ctor() 
--- End of inner exception stack trace 

--- at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) at System.Reflection.Assembly.CreateInstance(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) at Microsoft.Web.Editor.Host.WebEditor.get_Host() at Microsoft.Web.Editor.Host.WebEditor.GetSettings(String contentTypeName) at Microsoft.JSON.Editor.Settings.JSONSettings.get_Storage() at Microsoft.JSON.Editor.Settings.JSONSettings.get_SchemaCatalogs() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSON.Package.Schema.CatalogJSONSchemaSelector..ctor()
--- End of inner exception stack trace
--- at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.CreateValue() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.Create() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass53_0.<CreateExport>b__0() at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() at System.Lazy`1.get_Value() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.NetFxAdapters.MefV1ExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<UnwrapExport>b__1() at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export.GetExportedValueCore() at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export.get_Value() at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.GetCastedExportedValue[T](Export export) at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.<>c__DisplayClass11_0`2.<CreateStronglyTypedLazyOfTM>b__1() at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() at System.Lazy`1.get_Value() at Microsoft.Web.Editor.Composition.ComponentLocatorWithOrderingAndUnorderedParts`1.ImportMany()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and it was because of the [fips](/questions/tagged/fips) Algorithm policy enabled on the machine.

**Resolution:**

Disable FIPS Algoirthm policy via regedit and restart the Visual Studio.

**Location:**

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Lsa\FipsAlgorithmPolicy